# ElasticSearch: Nested Query: Same Query but different results

Tags: elasticsearch

So, I am having issues with Nested+Filter queries. I am firing same queries (except how json positions the key, value pairs) and getting different results (one right response and another throws error). Sounds crazy right? Well I tried it several times, cross-checked it, its true.

Successful Query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": {
                        "nested": {
                            "filter": {
                                "bool": {
                                    "must": {
                                        "nested": {
                                            "filter": {
                                                "bool": {
                                                    "must": [{
                                                        "term": {
                                                            "stream.tagging.tag": "some_tag"
                                                        }
                                                    }]
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "path": "stream.tagging"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "path": "stream"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "and": [{
                    "not": {
                        "term": {
                            "deleted": "true"
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    "term": {
                        "source": 11
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error Query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "and": [{
                    "not": {
                        "term": {
                            "deleted": "true"
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    "term": {
                        "source": 11
                    }
                }],
                "bool": {
                    "must": {
                        "nested": {
                            "filter": {
                                "bool": {
                                    "must": {
                                        "nested": {
                                            "filter": {
                                                "bool": {
                                                    "must": [{
                                                        "term": {
                                                            "stream.tagging.tag": "some_tag"
                                                        }
                                                    }]
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "path": "stream.tagging"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "path": "stream"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error Message:

```
nested: QueryParsingException[[stream_rules_test] No filter registered for [must]]; }]","status":400
```

Also note when I fire them individually, only nested and only filter queries, it works fine too. I hope I am not making some silly mistake, but I am almost sure I am not missing anything.

ES Version: 1.5

Comment: Which version of ES are you using?

Comment: @Val ElasticSearch 1.5

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be with the version with new versions not supporting "and: queries. Below query works all the time. Still confused why it doesn't work when key, value pairs are changed.

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must_not": {
                        "term": {
                            "deleted": "true"
                        }
                    },
                    "must": [{ 
                        "term": {
                            "source": 11
                            }
                        },{
                        "nested": {
                            "filter": {
                                "bool": {
                                    "must": {
                                        "nested": {
                                            "filter": {
                                                "bool": {
                                                    "must": [{
                                                        "term": {
                                                            "stream.tagging.tag": "some_tag"
                                                        }
                                                    }]
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "path": "stream.tagging"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "path": "stream"
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```